# What is the difference between addFilterQuery And setQuery in SoLR?

Tags: php, performance, solr, nosql

I am currently connecting Solr in PHP.

I am not able to understand which one to use for better performance **addFilterQuery** OR **setQuery**.

Also what is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 1):

**setQuery** performs with by default OR operator(if you are not mention any operator [`AND / NOT` etc] between the multiple field query) and it search for results in whole database.

**addFilterQuery** performs with only `AND` operator and involves on `setQuery` results.